# Changing textfield into textarea

Tags: tooltips

I hope I'm right here with my request and someone can help. I'm working on a website with Drupal, but am not a trained programmer.

I use a module which allows me to display a tooltip in Drupal. By default, this is defined as type "textfield" and therefore has a maximum of 128 characters. As I need more characters, I have changed the "textfield" into "textarea". As a result, I have more characters available. If I save the tooltip it is recognized and displayed correctly in the frontend. Only when I edit the tooltip again, the entered text is gone.

Here's the code (the change I made is on line 25):

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * module for adding a link to a block title tooltip.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function block_title_tooltip_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'block_admin_configure' || $form_id == 'block_add_block_form') {
    $block = new stdClass();
    $block->module = $form['module']['#value'];
    $block->delta = $form['delta']['#value'];
    $title_tooltip_data = block_title_tooltip_get_data($block);
    $form['settings']['block_title_tooltip'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Block Title Tooltip Settings'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => 0,
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['settings']['block_title_tooltip']['title_tooltip'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => t('Title Tooltip'),
      '#default_value' => $title_tooltip_data,
      '#description' => t('Block Title tooltip.'),
    );
    if (!isset($form['block_settings']['#weight'])) {
      $form['block_settings']['#weight'] = -1;
    }
    $form['#submit'][] = 'block_title_tooltip_form_submit';
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_alter().
 */
function block_title_tooltip_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if (isset($data['content']) && is_array($data['content'])) {
    $data['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'block_title_tooltip') . '/css/block_title_tooltip.css';
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_submit().
 */
function block_title_tooltip_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $block = new stdClass();
  $block->module = $form['module']['#value'];
  $block->delta = $form_state['values']['delta'];
  $title_tooltip = $form_state['values']['block_title_tooltip']['title_tooltip'];
  $data = array(
    'title_tooltip' => $title_tooltip,
  );
  if (empty($title_tooltip)) {
    block_title_tooltip_delete_data($block);
  }
  else {
    block_title_tooltip_save_data($block, $data);
  }
}

/**
 * Function to delete block data.
 *
 * @param object $block
 *   The block object.
 */
function block_title_tooltip_delete_data($block) {
  if (!isset($block->module) && !isset($block->delta)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  $result = db_delete('block_title_tooltip')
  ->condition('module', $block->module, '=')
  ->condition('delta', $block->delta, '=')
  ->execute();
}

/**
 * Function to save Block title tooltip data.
 *
 * @param object $block
 *   The block object.
 *
 * @param array $data
 *   Array containing data.
 */
function block_title_tooltip_save_data($block, $data) {
  if (empty($block->module) || empty($block->delta)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Remove old settings.
  $result = db_delete('block_title_tooltip')
  ->condition('module', $block->module)
  ->condition('delta', $block->delta)
  ->execute();

  // Save new settings.
  $result = db_insert('block_title_tooltip')
  ->fields(array(
      'module' => $block->module,
      'delta' => $block->delta,
      'tooltip' => $data,
      ))
    ->execute();
  drupal_set_message(t('Your configuration save.'));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function block_title_tooltip_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $user;
  if ($hook == 'block') {
    $data = block_title_tooltip_get_data($vars['block']);
    if ($data) {
      $vars['block']->title_tooltip = (isset($data['tooltip'])) ? $data['tooltip'] : NULL;
      $vars['block']->title_tooltip = $vars['block']->title_tooltip;
      $display = (isset($data['display'])) ? $data['display'] : TRUE;
      if (!empty($vars['block']->title_tooltip) && $display) {
        $arbitrary_array = array(
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'block_title_tooltip') . '/image/callout.gif',
          'attributes' => array('class' => 'block_title_tooltip'),
        );
        $vars['block']->subject = '<div class="tooltip">' . $vars['block']->subject . '<span>' . theme('image', $arbitrary_array) . check_plain($vars['block']->title_tooltip) . '</span></div>';
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Function to return the data associated with a block_title_tooltip.
 *
 * @param object $block
 *   object of Block
 *
 * @return array
 *   A renderable array containing display_link and title_tooltip variable.
 */
function block_title_tooltip_get_data($block) {
  if (!isset($block->module) && !isset($block->delta)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  $result = db_select('block_title_tooltip', 'btt')
  ->condition('btt.module', $block->module, '=')
  ->condition('btt.delta', $block->delta, '=')
  ->fields('btt', array('tooltip'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
  if (is_array($result)) {
    return $result;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to change so that the tooltip is stored properly. I suspect that under the heading "* Function to save tooltip title block data." something needs to be adjusted.

I also get this warning (maybe it has to do with it):

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given in check_plain() (Zeile 1573 von
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal722\includes\bootstrap.inc).

Perhaps somebody sees the mistake?

Comment: the db field probably needs to be increase in size

Answer (score 0):

This code is little bit crazy.

it saves tooltip to db, but in frontend it doesnt use it:

`function block_title_tooltip_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
     .......
     $vars['block']->title_tooltip = (isset($data['tooltip'])) ? $data['tooltip'] : NULL;
     $vars['block']->title_tooltip = $vars['block']->title_tooltip;`

in first line there is code from db, but it takes another value - from block settings.

so there are 2 ways to fix it:

1. probably in your tooltip db field there is set max length. So you need to changed to text. You need to update schema in .install file and write update function to update it.. or you can just change it directly in db. if you don't know how to fix .install file.
2. another option. I'm not sure it is going to work. write this:

   `function block_title_tooltip_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    echo""; print_r($form_state); die();`

this code will print all values of $form_state. I assume that somewhere inside $form_state there should be value of your tooltip. because it is available in frontend function. So search for it. And then if you find it use it instead of this: 

   `//change this line 
   '#default_value' => $title_tooltip_data,
   //to someting like this:
   '#default_value' => $form_state['title_tooltip']`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So it is because of the database (I am a beginner). I just googled "mysql change max length of field" and found this solution:

ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <col_name> VARCHAR(65536)

Would this work for me, too? Where whould I need to apply this code? You said "or just change it directely in db"...could you tell me how exactely I can do this?

Comment: you can download phpmyadmin and execute code there.